# Identity Toolkit "Trouble Signing In" link Android

Tags: android, spring-boot, endpoints, google-identity-toolkit

I've got identity toolkit set up for my android app almost completely -- I just need help setting up the endpoint for the link "Trouble Signing In" when authenticating with a username & password.

I've tried (to no avail) to follow the steps enumerated [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/web/required-endpoints#send_email_url).

I've noticed a couple weird things:
1) The request sent to my endpoint on the back end is actually a GET request as opposed to the POST I was expecting (as per the aforementioned docs).
2) When the request gets to my server, after calling

```
OobResponse oobResponse = getGitkitClient().getOobResponse(request);
```

I put a bunch of the oobResponse properties into my response (using Spring Boot, so I just return a jsonified Map). 
Here are the values I get:

```
{"newEmail": null,"oobResponse":"{\"error\": \"unknown request\"}","email": null,"action": null,"recipient": null}
```

This json object displays on my device after I click the "Trouble signing in" link.

Here's some more of my configuration if it's pertinent:

Android manifest file contains the lines:

```
...
<meta-data
    android:name="identitytoolkit.show_providers"
    android:value="Facebook,Google" />
<meta-data
    android:name="identitytoolkit.use_google_plus"
    android:value="false" />
<meta-data
    android:name="identitytoolkit.api_key"
    android:value="myKey" />
<meta-data
    android:name="identitytoolkit.server_client_id"
    android:value="myClientId" />
<meta-data
    android:name="identitytoolkit.server_widget_url"
    android:value="https://example.com/callback" />`
...
```

In the Google Developer Console for the Identity Toolkit API, here is how my URL Configuration is set up:

```
Widget URL: https://example.com/callback  
Sign-in Success URL: https://example.com/signInSuccess  
Sign-out URL: https://example.com/signOut  
Send email URL: https://example.com/sendEmail
```

Here are my Web Client URLs:

```
Authorized JavaScript origins: http://example.com  
Authorized Redirect URIs: https://example.com/callback
```

Any ideas, hints, or links to good tutorials that you know about? This is one of the last few things I need to finish before I release, please help!

<strike>**Update:**

After trying to fiddle around with the problem some more, I suspect my problem may be caused by the fact that I'm using Spring Boot. The request that Google says they expect is the javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, while Spring Boot uses the org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest. I've found and included the javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest .jar and I now accept that type of request in the method's signature that corresponds to the /callback path. I've also tried setting the type of the request in the signature to the WebRequest and casting it to the HttpServletRequest type when calling:</strike>

```
OobResponse oobResponse = getGitkitClient().getOobResponse((HttpServletRequest) request);
```

This is still not working. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<meta-data
    android:name="identitytoolkit.server_widget_url"
    android:value="**https://example.com/sendEmail**" />`

The value should be your Widget URL, not your send email endpoint.

[Here is the official step by step tutorial](https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/android/) on using Identity Toolkit in Android. Hope this helps!

Comment: Should I then handle calling the following method in the /callback path?   OobResponse oobResponse = getGitkitClient().getOobResponse(request);   I only have an android app, so I don't have an actual widget.

Comment: While I think you're correct, this still doesn't remedy the problem. I'll update my question with some more of my suspicions.

Comment: No, you should still handle the getOobResponse API call in you /sendEmail endpoint. /callback should be the widget page that hosts gitkit-widget javascript. The widget is necessary if you want to support features like reset password, because the widget will call your send email endpoint where you send the user an email with the link you get from getOobResponse(), once the "Trouble Signing In" link is clicked.

Comment: Great, I'll try it! Thanks for your help, @yanna! Do you happen to have a link to the docs where it describes how to make the gitkit-widget? I know I've seen it, but I ignored it, as I figured it was only for web-end projects.

Comment: Found [the link](https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/web/quickstart/java)! I'll give it a try as soon as I can!